# Ajax jQuery on success if statement double json_encode return underfined value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I trying to get **$comments_id,$comments_timestamp, $user_firstname, $user_lastname** values and pass back to ajax, but in the if statement was execute only one object array which is **['successful-submit-comment'] = true;**.

**Ajax**

```
$.ajax({
        type:'post',
        url:'getcomment_detail.php',
        data:{comment_id: comment_id,user_desc:user_desc},
        cache:false,
        dataType:'json',
        success: function (data){
            console.log(data);
            var ttes1 = data.comments_timestamp;
            alert(ttes1);


       }
});
```

**getcomment_detail.php** :

```
$u_id = $_SESSION['u_id'];
$submit_comment_status = array();

if($sql = "INSERT INTO comments (post_id, user_id, user_desc) VALUES ('$comment_id','$u_id','$user_desc')"){
        mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
        mysqli_close($conn);

        $get_comment_user_detail = "SELECT comments.id, comments.timestamp, user.firstname, user.lastname FROM comments INNER JOIN user ON user.id = comments.user_id WHERE user.id = $u_id ORDER BY comments.id DESC LIMIT 1";

        if($stmt = $conn->prepare($get_comment_user_detail)) {

            $stmt->execute();

            $stmt->bind_result($comments_id, $comments_timestamp, $user_firstname, $user_lastname);

            while ($stmt->fetch()) {

                $comments_userdetails = array(
                    'comments_id' => $comments_id,
                    'comments_timestamp' => $comments_timestamp,
                    'u_firstname' => $user_firstname,
                    'u_lastname' => $user_lastname
                );

                header('Content-Type: application/json');
                echo json_encode($comments_userdetails);
            }
            $stmt->close();
        }

        $submit_comment_status['successful-submit-comment'] = true;
        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        echo json_encode($submit_comment_status);
    }
```

**Console return value:**

[image]

**Alert return value:**

*Undefined*

Comment: i think you should do $submit = json_encode($submit_comment_status); print_r($submit); and then see what is the output

Comment: it same, $comments_userdetails not return value, and i still get undefined

Comment: You have two (2) `echo` in your PHP... One in a loop! Making it numerous.... Echo the `json_encode()` at last! Out of the loop. The expected result should be produced by only one `echo`.

Comment: Like the above comment, you must put a condition to use one echo only...

Comment: OKay, thx guys, i trying now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just put it into the array and return it all as a json file?

```
$comments_userdetails = array(
                'comments_id' => $comments_id,
                'comments_timestamp' => $comments_timestamp,
                'u_firstname' => $user_firstname,
                'u_lastname' => $user_lastname,
                'successful-submit-comment' => true
            );

            header('Content-Type: application/json');
            echo json_encode($comments_userdetails);
```

and in your ajax you just get the value like

```
console.log(data['successful-submit-comment']);
```